# Old Mac (10.5.8) With Deleted Folder of Pictures - Looking for a Data Rescue 3 license (or similar)

Tags: macos

I have my parents' old Mac Mini that's running Leopard (10.5.8).

It has a directory of old scanned pictures that was inadvertently deleted and that I'm trying to recover.  I have a trial version of Data Rescue 3 that finds the pics but it's in demo mode.  I've contacted ProSoftEng but they won't sell a license for the old version.

Does anyone have any other software that will run and that is either free or you can still buy a license for?  Alternately, does anyone have an old Data Rescue 3 license that I can buy?

Comment: Surprised Dat rescue didn’t mention their newer software will recover the files over target disk mode. But it looks like you have some options now.

Answer (score 1):

Try Disk Drill Basic.

Alternatively, boot the Mac Mini in *target mode*<sup>1</sup> and thereafter attach its disk to a newer Mac, which can run newer versions of data recovery software.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Boot into target mode using one of the following:

- If the computer is off, start it up while pressing and holding the <kbd>T</kbd> key.
- If the computer is on, choose **Apple menu** > **System Preferences**, click **Startup Disk**, then click **Target Disk Mode**.