# Access deceased business partner's iMac?

Tags: macos, imac, password, data-recovery

I have a user whose business partner had an iMac. The business partner passed away some time ago, but their iMac is still in their old office.

The user is wanting to begin using the iMac, as well as access some of the business' files that were on the iMac. The user does not have their business partner's login information.

At this point the system only boots to the deceased partner's login screen, whether soft or hard reboot is tried. So far it has ignored my attempts at using any of the MacOS startup keys, so I'm not able to try any of the multiple recovery options shown on Apple's support page or YouTube, or trying anything with Kali(I haven't even found any tutorials related to using Kali against MacOS). I recognized that the keyboard may still be connecting wirelessly which may be causing a delay in when the iMac recognizes and responds to the keypresses - even though the keyboard is also connected to the iMac by a cable. I'm going to try again with a standard hardwired cable and see if it helps.

I'm also planning to assist them with contacting Apple support, though I know contacting them as a business partner may be different from contacting support on behalf of a deceased relative.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry for your loss. However, why would you want to use Kali? See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). Try booting in Target mode, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443345/100490) to [Old Mac (10.5.8) With Deleted Folder of Pictures - Looking for a Data Rescue 3 license (or similar)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/443327/100490). If that helps I could post it as an answer.

Comment: I know with Kali that, at least for Windows, you can remove/reset account passwords. Though I haven't found any information for doing the same using Kali's tools for an Apple computer.